# Draw Rect and optimization

Tags: cocoa-touch, optimization, drawing

I have an `NSMutableArray` that's holding objects (the objects represent arcs);

Everytime I tap the screen, a circle is added to the array, and the draw rect sets needsupdate. I am not calling `drawRect:`, just telling it that it needs to update.

Everytime that `drawRect:` looks through the array of circles, is it redrawing *every* circle, or only what's new / hasn't changed from the previous time through?

If it does redraw every circle, are there any good practices to optimize against this?

Comment: What method do you call to let the view know that it needs to update?

Answer (score 1):

Your drawing code is doing exactly whatever it says -- if you've written it to draw every circle, then every circle is drawn. You can write your `drawRect:` method such that it takes into account the passed rectangle, which is the "dirty" portion of the view -- that portion which needs updating, but it's only worth doing so if you've determined, via testing and measurement, that your drawing is a performance issue.

Cocoa Touch *will* clip your drawing, though, so that *it* doesn't have to refresh the whole screen, if, instead of using `setNeedsDisplay`, you use `setNeedsDisplayInRect:`, passing an appropriate dirty rectangle. You could, for example, pass just the boundary rectangle of each new circle when one is added.

Comment: thanks for your help i didnt know about that method "setNeedsDisplayInRect:"

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you're calling setNeedsDisplay?  If so, that method does redraw the whole view.  You can use setNeedsDisplayInRect: if you only want to redraw a portion of your view.

Comment: yeah, i didnt have xcode open so i was guessing what the method was called "sets needsupdate" should have be "setNeedsDisPlay"